# Getting data from a submitted form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a very simple HTML quiz. It asks the user few questions about what kind of car they're looking for and suggests one. But I can't get the javascript to work. It's a very simple script so I don't know what I'm mising. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form id="form" action="">
<p>What size do you need?</p>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="compact">Compact<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="mid">Midsize<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="small">Small SUV<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="med">Medium SUV<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="big">Big SUV

<p>What kind of driving will you be doing?</p>
<input type="radio" name="drive" value="city">City/suburb driving<br>
<input type="radio" name="drive" value="mountain">Mountain driving

<p>Which would you rather have?</p>
<input type="radio" name="mpg" value="mpg">Good gas milage<br>
<input type="radio" name="mpg" value="performance">Performance

<p>How much do luxury features matter to you?</p>
<input type="radio" name="money" value="money">I'd rather save money and have less luxury features<br>
<input type="radio" name="money" value="luxury">I'd rather spend a little more and have luxury features.

<p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function() {
    size = document.querySelector('input[name = "size"]:checked').value;
    drive = document.querySelector('input[name = "drive"]:checked').value;
    mpg = document.querySelector('input[name = "mpg"]:checked').value;
    money = document.querySelector('input[name = "money"]:checked').value;         

    if (size == "compact" && drive == "city" && mpg == "mpg" && money == "money") 
    {
        result = "Prius";
    }   else {
        result = "something else";
    }
    document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = result; 
return false; // required to not refresh the page
};
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: @Eyad, you forgot to place <div id=suggestion></div> at your html?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw When you select those answers (compact, city, mpg, and money), the script is suppose to document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = result; In this case, your result will print as "Prius" but that is not happening. When you submit, nothing changes.

Comment: @nas it's there, i just didn't copy the whole code. After the closing </form> tag, I have <p id="suggestion"></p>

Comment: Do you maybe get error in console like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null`? If yes then you are trying to get element before it is created so move your script down before closing body tag.

Comment: @jakob No console errors. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Does the document.querySelector section looks alright to everyone? That's the part that I wasn't very sure about.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it works now. Anyone know how to convert repzero or @jonathandion's code into a switch statement? I tried it but it did not work. Not sure how to post that on here. if I press enter, it'll add this comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several issues.

First, you need to declare your variable using `var`. You need to set a default value for each radio button. Also from your example `document.getElementById("suggestion")` is never into the DOM.

[Here a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/w7Lhefta/10/)

Answer (score 0):

One issue,
you will notice that

```
document.querySelector('input[name = "size"]:checked').value;
```

will return an error when you press your submit button.  This error maybe caused by a user not selecting an option. If the user does not select an option then

`document.querySelector('input[name = "size"]:checked')` is null.
therefore `null.value` is invalid and your console shows this.

You can test each object if it is null  by using

```
 document.querySelector('input[name ="size"]:checked') ?
```

Here is a snippet

```js
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
  size = document.querySelector('input[name ="size"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name ="size"]:checked').value : "";
  drive = document.querySelector('input[name ="drive"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name ="drive"]:checked').value : "";
  mpg = document.querySelector('input[name ="mpg"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name ="mpg"]:checked').value : "";
  money = document.querySelector('input[name ="money"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name ="money"]:checked').value : "";



  if (size == "compact" && drive == "city" && mpg == "mpg" && money == "money") {
    result = "Prius";
  } else {
    result = "something else";
  }
  document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = result;
  return false; // required to not refresh the page
};
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
  <p>What size do you need?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="compact">Compact<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="mid">Midsize<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small">Small SUV<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="med">Medium SUV<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="big">Big SUV

  <p>What kind of driving will you be doing?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="drive" value="city">City/suburb driving<br>
  <input type="radio" name="drive" value="mountain">Mountain driving

  <p>Which would you rather have?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="mpg" value="mpg">Good gas milage<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mpg" value="performance">Performance

  <p>How much do luxury features matter to you?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="money" value="money">I'd rather save money and have less luxury features<br>
  <input type="radio" name="money" value="luxury">I'd rather spend a little more and have luxury features.

  <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
  <p id="suggestion">What kind of driving will you be doing?</p>
</form>
```